# Dynamically change the position of title from center to left?

Tags: html, css, angular, position, element

My problem is the following, I want the title to be postionned in the middle if no other elements are present in the toolbar, and on the left when there are other elements ( in my case, buttons).

How do I do such thing? Below are attached the pictures which show how I want my toolbar to look like.

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary" >

  <h1 id="app-title">{{title}}</h1>
  <div class="buttons" *ngIf="currentUser" [(ngClass)]="">
  <button mat-button routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active">Home</button>
  <button mat-button>About</button>
  <button mat-button>Contact</button>
  <button mat-button>Profile</button>
  <button mat-button (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
</div>
  
</mat-toolbar>
```

Left [image]

[image: centered]

Comment: I would dynamically add a class to the parent container to center everything if no buttons are present.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `CSS` pseudo-class `:only-child` to handle this.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-child)

> The :only-child CSS pseudo-class represents an element without any siblings. This is the same as :first-child:last-child or :nth-child(1):nth-last-child(1), but with a lower specificity.

```
#app-title {
  text-align: left;
}

#app-title:only-child {
  text-align: center;
}
```

However, in a more real-world scenario, I'd probably approach things using `flex`, in addition to `:only-child`. Setting the left and right `margin` to `auto` will center the element.

```css
.app-title:only-child {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.app {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  
  /* Ignore */
  align-items: center;
  border: 0.5px solid gray;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <h1 class="app-title">Title</h1>
</div>

<div class="app">
  <h1 class="app-title">Title</h1>
  <p>
    Another elemeent
  </p>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v8cg5k6e/)

Answer (score 0):

You may use `flex`, `flex-grow` on the possible extra tag and `margin:auto` on the title

example to demonstrate the idea from flex behavior.

```css
div[mat-toolbar]
/* udpdate that selector to match mat-toolbar element */

{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #3E51B7;
}

#app-title {
  margin: auto;
}

#app-title+* {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: solid 1px lightgray/* see me */
}


/* for the demo */

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
  /*optionnal */
  justify-content: end;
}
```

```html
<div mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <h1 id="app-title">{{title}}</h1>
  <div class="buttons" *ngIf="currentUser" [(ngClass)]="">
    <button mat-button routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active">Home</button>
    <button mat-button>About</button>
    <button mat-button>Contact</button>
    <button mat-button>Profile</button>
    <button mat-button (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<p>and see if standing alone ?</p>
<hr>


<div mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <h1 id="app-title">{{title & no sibblings}}</h1>

</div>
```